# C# Evernote API method ENSession.SharedSession.FindNotes() does not work properly any more

Tags: c#, api, evernote

I tried to use

```
var findNotes = ENSession.SharedSession.FindNotes(noteSearch, null, ENSession.SearchScope.DefaultScope, ENSession.SortOrder.Normal, 100);
```

method as before, but it didn't response properly. Since today it isn't working for some reason. This method just response with 0 elements despite the value of noteSearch parameter.

I should mention that my sandbox key is full access not basic. And there is no single error in this response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason my previous request from the task still does not work:

```
var findNotes = ENSession.SharedSession.FindNotes(ENNoteSearch.NoteSearch("monday"), null, ENSession.SearchScope.DefaultScope, ENSession.SortOrder.Normal, 100);
```

But somehow works this:

```
var findNotes = ENSession.SharedSession.FindNotes(ENNoteSearch.NoteSearch(""), null, ENSession.SearchScope.Personal, ENSession.SortOrder.Normal, 21).Where(x => x.Title == "monday");
```

Anyway my problem have been solved.